# Why is my variable is null?

Tags: java, xml, parsing

I do this

```
    package file;

    import java.io.IOException;

    import org.apache.log4j.Logger;
    import org.xml.sax.Attributes;
    import org.xml.sax.ContentHandler;
    import org.xml.sax.Locator;
    import org.xml.sax.SAXException;
    import org.xml.sax.XMLReader;
    import org.xml.sax.helpers.LocatorImpl;
    import org.xml.sax.helpers.XMLReaderFactory;

    public class GetNatureSax implements ContentHandler {

        private final static Logger _logger = Logger.getLogger(GetNatureSax.class.getName());
        private boolean isCurrentElement = false;
        private Locator locator;
        private String _parameterValue = null;

        public GetNatureSax() {
            super();
            locator = new LocatorImpl();
        }

        public String getValeurParametre() {
            return _parameterValue;
        }

        public void setDocumentLocator(Locator value) {
            locator = value;
        }

        public void startDocument() throws SAXException {}

        public void endDocument() throws SAXException {}

        public void startPrefixMapping(String prefix, String URI) throws SAXException {

        }

        public void endPrefixMapping(String prefix) throws SAXException {}

        public void startElement(String nameSpaceURI, String localName, String rawName, Attributes attributs)
        throws SAXException {
            if (localName.equals("Nature")) {
                isCurrentElement = true;
            }
        }

        public void endElement(String nameSpaceURI, String localName, String rawName) throws SAXException {

            if (localName.equals("Nature")) {
                isCurrentElement = false;
            }
        }

        public void characters(char[] ch, int start, int end) throws SAXException {
            if (isCurrentElement) {
                _parameterValue = new String(ch, start, end);
            }
        }

        public void ignorableWhitespace(char[] ch, int start, int end) throws SAXException {
            System.out.println("espaces inutiles rencontres : ..." + new String(ch, start, end) + "...");
        }

        public void processingInstruction(String target, String data) throws SAXException {
            System.out.println("Instruction de fonctionnement : " + target);
            System.out.println("  dont les arguments sont : " + data);
        }

        public void skippedEntity(String arg0) throws SAXException {}

        public void parseFichier(String i_fichierATraiter) {
            XMLReader saxReader;
            try {

                saxReader = XMLReaderFactory.createXMLReader("org.apache.xerces.parsers.SAXParser");
                saxReader.setContentHandler(new GetNatureSax());
                saxReader.parse(i_fichierATraiter);
                System.out.println(_parameterValue);
            } catch (SAXException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
```

My XML:

```
...
<Reference>
  <Nature>ACHAT</Nature> 
  <Statut>2</Statut> 
  <Type-Gest>RE</Type-Gest> 
  <Gest>RE_ELECTRA</Gest> 
  <Type-Res>D</Type-Res> 
  <Nb-h>24</Nb-h> 
</Reference>
...
```

why when it execute this line

> System.out.println(_parameterValue);

my variable is null and before when i debug my variable is not null

Comment: please delete such long comments when you are posting it here.

Comment: also please leave only the relevant code.

Comment: You are getting content of tag named `Nature`. Can you show us your XML too.

Comment: From what I see, it is null because you don't set it anywhere... Except in `characters()` but I see no code path guaranteeing that you get there before you print it.

Comment: It would help if you posted only relevant code. It would also help if you posted the code that uses GetNatureSax.

Comment: Btw, printing only the relevant code doesn't just help us -- there's a very good chance that in going through the process of finding out what the relevant code is, you'll have solved the problem yourself.

Comment: it would help using a debugger to find the root of the problem

Comment: If you set a breakpoint (or do a `System.out.println("I'm here")`) inside the `characters` function it is reached? What if you put it inside the if? Does a `System.out.println(_parameterValue)` inseide that function give any output?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because you instantiate a new `GetNatureSax` and give it to the `SaxReader` has a `Content Handler`.

So when the parsing has ended, it is the new `GetNatureSax` instance that have been modified and which have the field `_parameterValue` set, not the **current instance *(this)***.

Just modify your `parseFichier` method like this:

```
saxReader = XMLReaderFactory.createXMLReader("org.apache.xerces.parsers.SAXParser");
saxReader.setContentHandler(this);  // here
saxReader.parse(i_fichierATraiter);
System.out.println("Found: " + getValeurParametre());
```

Answer (score 1):

Using my debugger I can see you are using two GetNatureSax

```
  saxReader.setContentHandler(new GetNatureSax());
```

This creates a second GetNatureSax object where is where the value is being set.

Changing it to

```
 saxReader.setContentHandler(this);
```

fixed the problem.